# how can i get a single result from a database function in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to fetch the result of a database function to store it in a variable. In the case of this function, a receipt id is passed and the function returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the receipt is enabled. Try in the following ways:

```
 result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT receipt_enabled FROM schema.receipt_enabled(158800)") 
=> #<PG::Result:0x00556c7c374158 @connection=#<PG::Connection:0x00556c7d8ab3f0 @socket_io=nil, @notice_receiver=nil, @notice_processor=nil>> 

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT receipt_enabled FROM schema.receipt_enabled(158800)").to_a
 => [{"receipt_enabled"=>"f"}]

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT receipt_enabled FROM schema.receipt_enabled(158800)").rows
=> [["f"]]
```

I would need to do something similar to this

```
if result == true
    @showreceipt = true
else
    @showreceipt = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ActiveRecord::Result`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) has [`cast_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04972d9b9ef60796dc8f0917817b5392d61fcf09/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L104-L128) method (it uses `deserialize` under the hood)

```rb
query =
  <<~SQL
    SELECT receipt_enabled
    FROM schema.receipt_enabled(158800)
  SQL
```

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query).cast_values.flatten.first
# will return true or false
```